# Need C# to break on Selenium first chance exceptions

Tags: c#, selenium, exception

I'm debugging a Selenium test suite via Visual Studio.  I want exceptions that are thrown/caught to break, so I can find out what's missing, but I'm new to C#/Visual Studio, and I don't know what to select.

A sample exception block:

```
The thread '<No Name>' (0x75ac) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
A first chance exception of type 'OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException' occurred in WebDriver.dll
A first chance exception of type 'OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException' occurred in Selenium.WebDriverBackedSelenium.dll
A first chance exception of type 'Selenium.SeleniumException' occurred in Selenium.WebDriverBackedSelenium.dll
The thread '<No Name>' (0x7250) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

What do I select to have it stop on those first chance exceptions, so I can fix the code?

Thank you!

Comment: Are you using build in MsUnit or something else like NUnit?

Comment: We build using NUnit and the .NET Selenium WebDriver.

Comment: In this case you need attach visual studio debugger to the NUnit Process. In visual studio menu go to Debug -> Attach to process... and pick up the nunit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you select DEBUG -> Exceptions, there will be a window with a list of exception types and 2 columns, Thrown and User-unhandled. Make sure the 'Thrown' column is selected for Common Language Runtime Exceptions (if Selenium is clr). This will cause the debugger to break for exceptions that are managed with a try/catch.

edit

You may additionally need to select DEBUG -> Options and Settings and in Debugging -> General, deselect the 'Enable Just My Code'. Be careful though, this will cause symbols for .NET framework source to be downloaded, either immediately, or the next time you start debugging.